# any equivalent for MATLAB/Simulink/Sim Power System toolbox

Tags: software-recommendation, matlab

Is there any software/package which is equivalent to MATLAB/Simulink/Sim Power System toolbox?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab runs under ubuntu natively.  As far as Simulink check out  [Ubuntu Science / Alternatives To Proprietary Software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuScience/AlternativesToProprietarySoftware).

For Sim Power System Toolbox check out [Ubuntu for Engineers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEngineering).

Comment: I have checked the links but could not find a anything similar to Simpowersystem toolbox of Matlab /Simulink

Answer (score 1):

There are few which look similar, but depends about your taste and flavour which do you like most:

- [Freemat](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/)
- [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/)
- [Octave](http://www.scilab.org/)
- [GNUPlot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)

Give a look at these links..

Comment: I have checked Scilab and Octave but they are equivalent in MATLAB scripting but not for Simulink/Simpower system toolbox. I'm looking for a software for simulating power electronics/electrical machines circuits.

Comment: @user179711: I've already told you, it depends upon your taste and flavor. What about Freemat and GNUPlot?

Comment: Freemat and GNUPlot are also not for power electronic simulations

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python package I am currently developping as an equivalent of simulink:
https://github.com/masfaraud/BMSpy/wiki

Feel free to ask for new features!

Answer (score 0):

Surprised to see that nobody has suggested [Modelica language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelica) based platforms so far. It is definitely superior to SIMULINK, not just because there are free and open source implementations like [OpenModelica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenModelica) and [Jmodelica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JModelica.org), but also because it is a non-causal simulator. You can just simply code your model using differential and algebraic equations or use graphical interface just like SIMULINK.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Collimator](https://www.collimator.ai/) too. It's a model and simulation platform much like Simulink, but its browser based so simulations are run online and it also allows for collaboration with other people on the same model. It's coded in python so it integrates well with most python libraries: numpy, scipy, matplotlib, or even pytorch and tensorflow for AI and ML. It also lets you script your models via python notebook if you prefer.